# Autocomplete Ajax on cakephp 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, autocomplete

I want to know, how to create autocomplete in cakephp 2. I read on internet, but i can't find relevant info about my part.

Currently I load all data first at controller, assign to view then start the autocomplete from all datas. but this not efficient and takes time since the data could be alot. how can i filter the controller function to load only keyword i type on input? I am able to do this on PHP level, but i dunt know how on cakephp 2.

here my current codes on cakephp 2:

productcontroller this load all product on the stores:

```
$storeproducts = $this->get_storeproduct_autocomplete($sale['Sale']['store_id']);
```

this is the input at my view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode/Nama barang..." name="search_keyword" id="searchProduct" />
```

and at the bottom of the view i put script:

```
$(function() {
        var availableProduct = [
        <?php 
        foreach ($products as $spro):
            $label = addslashes($spro['Product']['barcode'].' '.$spro['Product']['product_name']);

            ?>
            { label:"<?php echo $label;?>", value:"<?php echo $spro['Product']['barcode'];?>" },
            <?php
        endforeach;
        unset($spro);
        ?>
        ];
        $( "#searchProduct" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableProduct,
            delay: 200,
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

By Using Those code, the autocomplete is working, but it load whole record first, not as the filter i type. and the input field is filled with barcode, or whatever value i set, but i want it show the product name, and when i submit, it got product id, can we do that?

**Edit 1:**
Update my controller, create new function to do the data filter that called via ajax:

```
public function ajax_get_autocomplete_storeproduct($keyword, $store_id)
    {
        $result = array();

        $storeproducts = $this->StoreProduct->find('all', array(
            'fields'=>array('StoreProduct.id', 'StoreProduct.stok'),
            'conditions'=>array('Product.deleted'=>0, 
                                'StoreProduct.stok >'=>0, 
                                'StoreProduct.store_id'=>$store_id,
                                'OR'=>array(
                                    'Product.barcode LIKE' => "%$keyword%",
                                    'Product.product_name LIKE' => "%$keyword%",
                                )
                               )));

        //how to set the value to view ?

        return new CakeResponse(array('body'=>json_encode($result)));
    }
```

How to set the key:value from controller to data response at ajax?

Comment: You can use bootstrap  autocomplete

Comment: is there docs page for that?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, you can call ajax function in autocomplete. So on page load, you dont have to do anything. But on key type, ajax function will be called.

```
$("#searchProduct").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "add url for function call in ajax",
              dataType: "json",
              type: "post",
              data: {key: value},// if you want to send any values to ajax call, you can do it here.
              success: function (data) {
                   response(data);
              }
          });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      delay: 200// im not sure why u need delay.
 });
```

In that function for which ajax call goes, populate the array there and echo the array in json format using `echo json_encode($array);`. It will work.

**Edit**

Your controller function should look like this

```
function products() {
    $array[0]['name'] = "Product - 1";
    $array[0]['price'] = 100;
    $array[1]['name'] = "Product - 2";
    $array[1]['price'] = 200;
    // like above populate all your products in to an array.

    // at last add this line
    echo json_encode($array);// this will generate key: value what you asked.
}
```

Comment: Ic.. but how can i send the data format key: value from controller? *i update my question qith updated controller code? just do find list on controller?

Comment: the autocomplete is not working, should we need library to do it? instead of jQuery

Comment: I already have it loaded, my other ajax and jquery working, but when i add the script, all other not working suddenly, no info on console

Comment: there is no error on console, nothing response on typing in the field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146229/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-gabriel).